# How to find the right size box?

Tags: sql, oracle, logistics

This is a hard question and I hope I can get the answer here.

The question is to find the right size box which allow the logistic business to save the money when shipping.

We have 2 tables which are boxes and products.

Boxes table contains each ID and dimensions per box.
'w' for wide, 'd' for depth and 'h' for height. Please assume we have just 3 box samples for our convenience.

Products table includes also product ID, dimensions. Dimensions has the same meaning as boxes table.
'layable' means the product can be packaged not only straight position but also layable position. For instance product 'g' is a fragile bottle not being able to put horizontal position in the box. Thus this is 'n' in layable column.

This question needs to query each product ID with the right size box.
The right size box means the product needs to be shipped with box that is the least space.

Hope your kind help. Thanks.

boxes:

| size | w | d | h |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| S | 353 | 250 | 25 |
| M | 450 | 350 | 160 |
| L | 610 | 460 | 460 |

products:

| ID | w | d | h | layable |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 350 | 250 | 25 | y |
| b | 450 | 250 | 160 | y |
| c | 510 | 450 | 450 | y |
| d | 350 | 250 | 25 | y |
| e | 550 | 350 | 160 | y |
| f | 410 | 400 | 430 | n |
| g | 350 | 240 | 25 | n |
| h | 450 | 350 | 160 | n |
| i | 310 | 360 | 430 | n |

Expected output:

| ID | size |
| --- | --- |
| a | S |
| b | M |
| ... | .... |
| ... | .... |
| ... | .... |
| g | S |

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm . . . I'm not quite sure how "layable" fits in.  But you want the smallest box that is as big as or bigger than each dimension.  The basic idea is:

```
select p.*,
       (select b.size
        from boxes b
        where b.w >= p.w and b.d >= p.d and b.h >= p.h
        order by b.size desc -- happens to works because S > M > L
        limit 1
       ) as size
from products p
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer althought this can't solve 'layable' issue. Good tip.

Comment: The OP reposted the question, and posted his own attempt. From that attempt, we see that even for non-layable items (which he also explains better in the other post), the product can be **rotated** within the box. So least of (width, depth) of product must be compared to least of (width, depth) of box, and greatest to greatest.